# Можно ли в extjs спустится вниз по DOM по названию?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom

Есть вьюшка board,в ней расположено несколько контейнеров,внутри которых таб панели и групбаттоны.Раньше спускались до элемента костыльным способом:

```
this.up('board').items.items[3].items.items[i].toggle(false);
```

При нажатии на кнопку вызывалась строчка выше в цикле и пробегалась по всем кнопкам,выставляя им выключенное положение.Вопрос,я добавил плюс один контейнер и само собой что вся эта система рухнула как бомба на хирасиму.Мне надо это как то восстановить,восстановливать таким же костыльным способом нет желания,но я задал параметр name для каждой из кнопок,можно ли как нибудь спуститься к ним по этому параметру?
чтобы было что то наподобе

```
this.up('board').down('Button1').toggle(false);
```

?

просто xtype у каждой кнопки стандартный button,поэтому спустится по xtype не получится,а Ext.getCmp использовать мне категорически запрещенно из за ухудшения производительности сайта.
заранее спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было делать так:

```
this.up('board').down('button1[name=NameButton1]').toggle(false);
```

и главное,обратите внимание на пробелы,с пробелами не кушается